# Can't find the name of a face in the *Buffer List* menu

Tags: faces, buffer-list

[image: buffer screenshot]
The green arrow points to the face `header-line`; so I'm good there.

But I have no idea what specific face the red arrow is pointing to.

Does anybody know?

Comment: My default color is a grey background for everything in the header-line when I type `M-x list-buffers` -- no purple, no blue.  What theme, or other gizmo/doohickey, are you using that changes the default behavior?  Are you using `M-x list-buffers` or a different method of getting the `*Buffer List*`?

Comment: I set all the faces that I don't use or don't know to a `purple` background and a `black` foreground. So I know that it's one of those faces in `M-x list-buffers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `fixed-pitch` font-face.

You can find and customize this face by issuing the command: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-faces-display`

Comment: @Drew Heck yeah it would be! Just edited to be more succinct.